# .htaccess Giving Internal Error instead of 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay so I have a file structure setup where all my pages are setup in a folder called pages.

I need the htaccess redirect so that way `example.com/page1` goes to `example.com/page/page1.php`.

So, I used the `.htaccess` below. My problem is, is that when I have this set, I get an 500 error instead of the custom 404 error page appearing.

```
AllowOverride All
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [L]
```

Any suggestions on what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: A 500 error will obviously not forward you to a 404 error-document.

Comment: Clearly... that's not what i'm trying to do. What i'm trying to do is setup a custom 404 page and when I do that, I get a 500 error instead.

Comment: and what does the error say? ;)

Comment: What happens when you open `example.com/pages/page1.php`?

Comment: Try looking at the server logs. My guess would be the `AllowOverride` call. IIRC this is only allowed directly in the apache config as it defines WHAT can be overridden in a .htaccess file.

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error

An internal server error has occured."

Comment: Can you make an edit with the code of page1.php? Maybe there's something wrong there.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify more. The redirection works fine. However, when I go to a page that doesnt exist, I get a error 500 error instead of a 404 page. I added the `AllowOverride`call because I read some other posts with similar issues and the person said that adding that worked. Doesn't work with or without it though

Comment: Look at the error log of your apache.

Comment: I can't i'm on shared hosting

Comment: Your code have critical problems. So when you want call any images for example, you would forwarded to .php file. Also there is infinite loop. When you call /pages/404.php it would forwarded to /pages/pages/404.php.php and it to /pages/pages/pages/404.php.php.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
AllowOverride All
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /pages/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`AllowOverride` is not allowed there, you should embed it in a `<Directory>` section. See also the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

```
<Directory /path/to/my/directory>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```